# Python method be aware the self.variable changed

Tags: python, class, methods

I want to make a class function be aware of the self.var whether it is changed by its inherent child class. Like class C1 is the P's child class, and it changes the var's value, the func does A. When the "var" is not changed, like C2, then do B.

```
class P(object):
    var =  "original"

    def func(self):
        if # self.var is changed by child instance:
            do A
        else:
            do B

class C1(P):
    var = "changed"

class C2(P):
    pass

c1 = C1
c2 = C2

c1.func() # do B
c2.func() # do A
```

For the reason I am doing this and more complex explanation.

I need to revise the openstack horizon [code](https://github.com/openstack/horizon/blob/master/horizon/tabs/base.py) to fullfill my own function:

```
class TabGroup(html.HTMLElement):
    ......
    template_name = "horizon/common/_tab_group.html"
    ......
    def render(self):
        return render_to_string(self.template_name, {"tab_group": self})
```

The TabGroup is usually inherited by other children, And some of them change template_name, some of them not. I want the render method be aware of template_name if it is changed by its child, and do different render accordingly.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is your _actual_ goal? (I.e., why are you trying to do this?) There's probably a better solution.

Comment: can't you use `if self.var != "original":` ?

Comment: @Chris, yes, thx for XY problem link, I update my quesiton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `var` is a class attribute, you could simply check if the value for the instance is different from the parent class:

```
class P(object):
    var = "original"

    def func(self):
        if self.var != P.var:
            print "DO A"
        else:
            print "DO B"

class C1(P):
    var = "changed"

class C2(P):
    pass

c1 = C1()
c2 = C2()

c1.func()  # Do A
c2.func()  # Do B
```

Another more general option, might be to define a subclass of `P` with the `func` method and use that as the parent for `C1` and `C2` classes. Then, we can make use of [super](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) to access the parent attribute. As follows:

```
class P(object):
    var = "original"

class PChild(P):
    def func(self):
        if self.var != super(PChild, self).var:
            print "DO A"
        else:
            print "DO B"

class C1(PChild):
    var = "changed"

class C2(PChild):
    pass

c1 = C1()
c2 = C2()

c1.func()
c2.func()
```

Comment: the first solution is brilliant, more simple and easy to understand. Why you say the second one is more general option?

Comment: The second one would also work if ``var`` was an *instance* attribute of the parent. The first one only works when ``var`` is a class attribute.

Answer (score 2):

To tell when a property on a class is changed, use the `__setattr__` magic method. Here's how you'd use it on a class:

```
class AttributeCatcher(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # to declare without __setattr__ firing we put it directly into self.__dict__
        self.__dict__['whatever'] = 'spam'

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        self.__dict__[name] = value
        print('{} changed to {}'.format(name, value))


a = AttributeCatcher()
a.whatever = 'eggs'
# outputs "whatever changed to eggs"
```

From there, it's not much of a stretch to create a `set` to store changes in:

```
class AttributeCatcher(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__['whatever'] = 'spam'
        self.__dict__['changes'] = set()

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        self.__dict__[name] = value
        self.__dict__['changes'].add(name)

    def func(self):
        if 'whatever' in self.changes:
            print('DO A')
        else:
            print('DO B')

a = AttributeCatcher()
a.whatever = 'eggs'
a.func() #outputs "DO A"

b = AttributeCatcher()
b.func() #outputs "DO B"
```

Though putting things into `self.__dict__` directly feels a bit hacky, this gives you a flexible way to check for changes on any amount of class variables.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest solution is to just define a private variable on the class and then check whether the value is the same (not actually protected) :

```
class P(object):
    __private = "original"
    var =  __private

    def func(self):
        if self.var == self.__private:
            do A
        else:
            do B
```

Now, this allows people to change the __private variable if they need to, but accessing it from outside the class means it will be accessed as follows:

```
>>> P._P__private
'original'
>>> P._P__private = 'newvalue'
```

This allows you to define a reasonable starting point to then check against whenever "var" is overridden, but also allow someone who **needs to** that they can override the value, while strongly suggesting they do not.

EDIT: Updated since methods and class variables with a leading underscore are protected, two leading underscores are private.